# Accessing Angular 9 route in subfolder directly throws 404?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have an Angular 9 app hosted in a domain subfolder. This is reflected in the index.html base tag, which looks like this:

```
<base href="/subfolder/">
```

The app behaves perfectly when run in local, without base subfolder:

```
<base href="/">
```

When the routing is accessed directly, the specific subpage loads correctly, like so:

```
http://localhost:4200/user/user-1
```

But that is not the case in production, where **when trying to access the subpage directly, will result in a 404**.

My routing module looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ExhibitorMainViewComponent } from './exhibitor-main-view/exhibitor-main-view.component';
import { ExhibitorDetailsComponent } from './exhibitor-details/exhibitor-details.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ExhibitorMainViewComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'user/:userId',
    component: ExhibitorDetailsComponent
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I'm pretty sure is related to the subfolder, but I couldn't debug it yet.

Any pointers?

Comment: are you sure the base href ends in "/"? I think that is `<base href="/subfolder">`

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the path of your subfolder when launching a build

`ng build --prod --deploy-url /subfolder/ --base-href /subfolder/`